# Angular [attr.href] condition with ng-click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an Angular5 application with a bootstrap tab control. I set the `href` of a tab to `#` if the property `modelChanged` is true, otherwise I set it to `#tab1` (or `#tab2`):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
    <li class="active">
        <a (click)="changeTab()" [attr.href]="modelChanged ? '#':'#tab1'" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a (click)="changeTab()" [attr.href]="modelChanged ? '#':'#tab2'" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So basically I am able to change the tab if  `modelChanged` is set to false, othwerise not.

Now I wan't to use a function called `changeTab()` where I change the `modelChanged` property to false and would expect that the tab change from 1 to 2 but it doesn't until I click the tab again:

```
changeTab() {
   modelChanged = false;
}
```

Anyone knows a solution for that?

Sorry that I don't have a working plunker but I think some of you will be able to answer my question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do the same

1) in your click specify modelChanged = !modelChanged,

```
[click]="modelChanged = !modelChanged"
```

2) `[click]="modelChanged = changeTab()"`
and in your controller specify the changeTab function like this

```
function changeTab(){
//do something
return false;
}
```